# Is it necessary/useful to include the publishers in the list of editorial board memberships?

Tags: publications, cv, faculty-application

When listing the journals in which you are a member of its editorial board, is it necessary or useful (maybe overdoing) to include the publisher, impact factor or any further information?

We had a debate among colleagues and there were two opposite opinions:

1. Any further information is superfluous, as the audience should know the journals, as the publishers are not mentioned in the list of publications too.
2. Because of numerous new journals, the audience may not understand the journal's reputation if not mentioning some further information.

WHat do you think? What is the most professional/standard/acceptable approach?

Comment: Who is the audience? Is this your tenure file?

Answer (score 2):

Unless you work in exactly the same area as someone else, you likely have no idea how good a journal is. For example, I know that the SIAM Journal on Numerical Analysis is good -- but is the Journal of Number Theory good? the Journal of Mathematical Sciences? But if I know that one of these is published by a professional society located in the US or Western Europe, then I can infer that it is likely a good journal; whereas if the journal is published by a company I've never heard of and that is located in Egypt or India, then I may have my doubts.

So, yes, I think it *is* useful to add the publisher.